# selenium.type() works but no text is shown in the field

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-rc

I have a few lines of Selenium RC Java code that are supposed to type some text into a text box. The text box is part of a form, and I am able to fill in other text boxes throughout the web page. However, my line of code that goes `selenium.type(id, text)` gets executed and the code continues without actually typing anything into the box. The Id I am using to denote the location of the text box is unique on the page to the box I'm trying to fill. Unfortunately I cannot share a URL of the exact page as it is part of a product I am running on my machine.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! I didn't realize the html elements I was trying to access were in an iframe and I needed to select it. Sorry!